# Reading a Java .class file

Tags: java, code-generation, bytecode, decompiling, .class-file

I want to write a tool which generates some code using a compiled `.class` file as input. Specifically, I want to read from this class file:

- Methods, with annotations
- Method parameters, with annotations

The input class file will likely refer to several types that are not in the tool's classpath. This is ok, I don't need to do anything with them, just need to read fully qualified type names as strings. I do need to get some information from the annotations, but they will be in the tool's classpath.

Is there a library which I can use for this purpose? It would be nice if the API was a bit like the reflection API, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: **Did you checked `http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui` ?**

Comment: @Creative MITian: That doesn't seem to be what I need. I don't need to decompile the code, I just need the meta-information (that you can access via reflection at runtime). I also need a library to embed in my tool, but that decompiler is a tool itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASM http://asm.ow2.org/ allows you to read a class from a file/input stream without class loading it. It allows you to see annotations which are not loaded at runtime.  It can also be used to modify the class byte code/annotations/method etc.

Comment: can it directly read .class files from the jar or the jar needs to be extracted first?

Comment: @gaurav This library supports reading an InputStream which can be a resource from the class path (or a Jar file)

Answer (score 4):

The [javap tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) included with the JDK probably already does what you're after.

Comment: It does appear so. The linked page doesn't show any annotations, but I assume they're there. Can I use its library directly, without running the command line tool and parsing the output?

Comment: You can get all the information with the reflection API, but for that the classes you want to analyze need to be on the classpath.

Comment: The output of javap is not intended to be consumed by a program. It has numerous omissions and ambiguities and is only suitable as a quick debugging tool.

Comment: @Antimony My answer was meant as follows: instead of writing such a tool yourself, you don't need to because such a tool already exists in the JDK, which is javap. I am not suggesting that you write a tool and parse the output of javap.

Comment: And my point is that javap does not satisfy the request of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at two things [`Reflection API`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and [`Decompiler`](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: Wrong: THe q said he wanted to read from the class file which does not load the class into the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use spring class scanning.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
String basePackage = "org/springframework/samples/petclinic";
Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents(basePackage);
for (BeanDefinition component : components) {
    System.out.printf("Component: %s\n", component.getBeanClassName());
}
```

for more information you can look into spring [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) for finding out all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to generating the .class file then the [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) should be able to help.

Comment: The Reflection API must first load the class, its not quite the same as attempting to read the same info from the file before loading.